# Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

I am writing a security system that denies access to unauthorized users.

```
name = input("Hello. Please enter your name: ")
if name == "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

It grants access to authorized users as expected, but it also lets in unauthorized users!

```
Hello. Please enter your name: Bob
Access granted.
```

Why does this occur? I've plainly stated to only grant access when `name` equals Kevin, Jon, or Inbar. I have also tried the opposite logic, `if "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar" == name`, but the result is the same.

---

<sub>This question is intended as the canonical duplicate target of this very common problem. There is another popular question [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) that has the same fundamental problem, but the comparison targets are reversed. This question should not be closed as a duplicate of that one as this problem is encountered by newcomers to Python who might have difficulties applying the knowledge from the reversed question to their problem.</sub>

<sub>For `in` instead of `==`, there are solutions here: [How to test the membership of multiple values in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/how-to-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)</sub>

Comment: Variations of this problem include `x or y in z`, `x and y in z`, `x != y and z` and a few others. While not exactly identical to this question, the root cause is the same for all of them. Just wanted to point that out in case anyone got their question closed as duplicate of this and wasn't sure how it's relevant to them.

Comment: I disagree with the argument that this should not be closed as a duplicate. The comparison may be reversed, but that is irrelevant--the problem and the solution(s) are the same. As the post's revision history shows, many users (including gold badge holders and diamond moderators) seem to agree.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

In many cases, Python looks and behaves like natural English, but this is one case where that abstraction fails. People can use context clues to determine that "Jon" and "Inbar" are objects joined to the verb "equals", but the Python interpreter is more literal minded.

```
if name == "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar":
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if (name == "Kevin") or ("Jon") or ("Inbar"):
```

Which, for user Bob, is equivalent to:

```
if (False) or ("Jon") or ("Inbar"):
```

The `or` operator [chooses the first operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680) that is ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695), i.e. which [would satisfy an `if` condition](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (or the last one, if none of them are "truthy"):

```
if "Jon":
```

Since "Jon" is truthy, the `if` block executes. That is what causes "Access granted" to be printed regardless of the name given.

All of this reasoning also applies to the expression `if "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar" == name`. the first value, `"Kevin"`, is true, so the `if` block executes.

---

There are three common ways to properly construct this conditional.

1. Use multiple `==` operators to explicitly check against each value:

   ```
   if name == "Kevin" or name == "Jon" or name == "Inbar":
   ```
2. Compose a collection of valid values (a set, a list or a tuple for example), and use the `in` operator to test for membership:

   ```
   if name in {"Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"}:
   ```
3. Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) to explicitly check against each value in a loop:

   ```
   if any(name == auth for auth in ["Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"]):
   ```

In general the second should be preferred as it's easier to read and also faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('name == "Kevin" or name == "Jon" or name == "Inbar"',
    setup="name='Inbar'")
0.0960568820592016
>>> timeit.timeit('name in {"Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"}', setup="name='Inbar'")
0.034957461059093475
>>> timeit.timeit('any(name == auth for auth in ["Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"])',
    setup="name='Inbar'")
0.6511583919636905
```

---

For those who may want proof that `if a == b or c or d or e: ...` is indeed parsed like this. The built-in `ast` module provides an answer:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.parse("a == b or c or d or e", "<string>", "eval")
<ast.Expression object at 0x7f929c898220>
>>> print(ast.dump(_, indent=4))
Expression(
    body=BoolOp(
        op=Or(),
        values=[
            Compare(
                left=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
                ops=[
                    Eq()],
                comparators=[
                    Name(id='b', ctx=Load())]),
            Name(id='c', ctx=Load()),
            Name(id='d', ctx=Load()),
            Name(id='e', ctx=Load())]))
```

As one can see, it's the boolean operator `or` applied to four sub-expressions: comparison `a == b`; and simple expressions `c`, `d`, and `e`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to choose a tuple `("Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar")` instead of  a set `{"Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"}`  ?

Comment: Not really, since both work if the values are all hashable. Set membership testing has better big-O complexity than tuple membership testing, but constructing a set is a little more expensive than constructing a tuple. I think it's largely a wash for small collections like these. Playing around with timeit, `a in {b, c, d}` is about twice as fast as `a in (b, c, d)` on my machine. Something to think about if this is a performance-critical piece of code.

Comment: [Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25368337/953482) recommends set literals for membership testing. I'll update my post.

Comment: In modern Python, it recognizes that the set is a constant and makes it a `frozenset` instead, so the constructing set overhead is not there. `dis.dis(compile("1 in {1, 2, 3}", '<stdin>', 'eval'))`

Comment: FWIW I think you should re-add the tuple as that is simpler for folks to understand than a set.

Comment: @endolith Doesn't much matter that it's a frozenset but that it's prepared at compile-time, and at runtime the whole already built set is simply used. Although that only applies if the set is indeed a constant literal, which it isn't in `a in {b, c, d}`, since that depends on the runtime values of the variables a, b and c. Kevin, did you actually test *that* with timeit? With `a, b, c, d = range(4)`, I get ~125 ns for `a in {b, c, d}` and ~90 ns for `a in (b, c, d)`. So for me, the set is much *slower*, not twice as fast. Even for this worst case for tuple, where the search value isn't found.

Answer (score 8):

## Summarising all existing answers

###### (And adding a few of my points)

### Explanation :

```
if name == "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar":
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if (name == "Kevin") or ("Jon") or ("Inbar"):
```

Which, for user Bob, is equivalent to:

```
if (False) or ("Jon") or ("Inbar"):
```

**NOTE : Python evaluates the logical value of any non-zero integer as `True`. Therefore, all Non-empty lists, sets, strings, etc. are evaluable and return `True`**

The `or` operator chooses the first argument with a positive truth value.

Therefore, "Jon" has a positive truth value and the if block executes, since it is now equivalent to

```
if (False) or (True) or (True):
```

That is what causes "Access granted" to be printed regardless of the name input.

### Solutions :

**Solution 1 :** Use multiple `==` operators to explicitly check against each value

```
if name == "Kevin" or name == "Jon" or name == "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

**Solution 2 :** Compose a collection of valid values (a set, a list or a tuple for example), and use the `in` operator to test for membership *(faster, preferred method)*

```
if name in {"Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"}:
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

OR

```
if name in ["Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"]:
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

**Solution 3 :** Use the basic *(and not very efficient)* `if-elif-else` structure

```
if name == "Kevin":
    print("Access granted.")
elif name == "Jon":
    print("Access granted.")
elif name == "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 condition checks in `if name == "Kevin" or "Jon" or "Inbar":`

- name == "Kevin"
- "Jon"
- "Inbar"

and this if statement is equivalent to

```
if name == "Kevin":
    print("Access granted.")
elif "Jon":
    print("Access granted.")
elif "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

Since `elif "Jon"` will always be true so access to any user is granted

### Solution

---

You can use any one method below

**Fast**

```
if name in ["Kevin", "Jon", "Inbar"]:
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

**Slow**

```
if name == "Kevin" or name == "Jon" or name == "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

**Slow + Unnecessary code**

```
if name == "Kevin":
    print("Access granted.")
elif name == "Jon":
    print("Access granted.")
elif name == "Inbar":
    print("Access granted.")
else:
    print("Access denied.")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Not-empty lists, sets, strings, etc. are evaluable and, therefore, return True.

Therefore, when you say:

```
a = "Raul"
if a == "Kevin" or "John" or "Inbar":
    pass
```

You are actually saying:

```
if "Raul" == "Kevin" or "John" != "" or "Inbar" != "":
    pass
```

Since at least one of "John" and "Inbar" is not an empty string, the whole expression always returns True!

## The solution:

```
a = "Raul"
if a == "Kevin" or a == "John" or a == "Inbar":
    pass
```

or:

```
a = "Raul"
if a in {"Kevin", "John", "Inbar"}:
    pass
```

Comment: good otherwise but "You are actually saying:" is **wrong**, that's not how `or` works. The value of the expression is `"John"`, not `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple engineering problem, let's simply it a bit further.

```
In [1]: a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4
In [2]: a==b
Out[2]: False
```

But, inherited from the language C, Python evaluates the logical value of a non zero integer as True.

```
In [11]: if 3:
    ...:     print ("yey")
    ...:
yey
```

Now, Python builds on that logic and let you use logic literals such as or on integers, and so

```
In [9]: False or 3
Out[9]: 3
```

Finally

```
In [4]: a==b or c or d
Out[4]: 3
```

The proper way to write it would be:

```
In [13]: if a in (b,c,d):
    ...:     print('Access granted')
```

For safety I'd also suggest you don't hard code passwords.

Answer (score 2):

### Using `match`/`case` in Python 3.10 and above

Python 3.10 [adds a new syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html) to the language. It's officially described as "structural pattern matching", but most people call it according to the syntax: "`match`/`case`".

- [Technical specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/)
- [Motivation and rationale](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/) (i.e., why it was added, and what inspired the design)
- [Official tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/)

We can use this special syntax for an example like in the question, by making one "case" that matches all the accepted usernames, and using the "wildcard" case `_` in place of the `else`. Thus:

```
name = input("Hello. Please enter your name: ")
match name:
    case "Kevin" | "Jon" | "Inbar":
        print("Access granted.")
    case _:
        print("Access denied.")
```

Note that cases are "combined" using `|`, not `or`. This is a special syntax: Python **does not** try to compute `"Kevin" | "Jon" | "Inbar"` first (`|` doesn't work with strings), but instead *interprets the entire line differently* because it starts with `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides some other rather rarer [useful cases for the walrus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297705/13629335) already mentioned. This also tend to be a useful case as well.

```py
def calc_value():
    return 43

if (v := calc_value()) == 43 and v > 42:
    print('happy short, efficient and readable code')
```

This works because each part of the [`if-statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) is read separately. So `(v := calc_value())` is executed and a value is assigned to `v` and if the first fails, you still have v in the namespace for different conditions or calculations.

Answer (score -4):

## Approaches

### How a data scientist approaches this problem

The simplest way possible is to eliminate the need for comparison operators and use a list. This looks impressive on security systems because you learn to access ORMs.

```
user = input("Enter name: ")

if user in {"Bob", "Kevin", "Joe"}:
   print("Access granted, " + str(user) + ".")
else:
   print("Access denied.")
```

Or, you can resemble the *exact* same code above, just put the list of registered users in their own list:

```
user = input("Enter name: ")
users = {"Bob", "Kevin", "Joe", "a million more users if you like"}

if user in users:
   print("Access granted, " + str(user) + ".")
else:
   print("Access denied.")
```

If you wanted to complete this protocol safely without the risk of attack, set up double parameters. This would check your mini-ORM for `first` and `last` name fields, as well as a `password` or `secret question` key. Objects can be sorted like this if you want to efficiently lazy-load user credentials without hashing:

```
def lazy(i):
   j = 0 # For example
   while j < i:
      yield j
      j += 1
```

The loop will consume **only** the yielded values to save time and energy on your system:

You can then do something with the iterated list:

```
for j in lazy_range(10):
   do_something_here(j)
```

This problem can be approached from any angle: memory management, security, or simply by an organic list or packaged ORM.